# HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess rewrite to index.php

Tags: html, .htaccess, indexing, url-rewriting, boilerplate

My question is:

if i add the following code at the bottom of .htaccess file of HTML5 Bilerplate

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this will send all REQUEST_URI to my index.php so I can handle them but will it break some of the rules from the .htaccess file already defined above? And if its wrong, what should be added?

Answer (score 0):

The rules you have posted above are already present in the .htaccess of HTML5 boilerplate (under the heading `# Built-in filename-based cache busting`)

```
# Uncomment to enable.
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
# </IfModule>
```

You can uncomment them by removing the '#' at the beginning of each line.
And change the 5th line to allow your rule for favicon.ico:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico)$ $1.$3 [L]
```

**Edit:** To direct all requests to index.php, I have modified the rules under `# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs` in this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC]
</IfModule>
```

In general you should put your own rules at the beginning of the .htaccess file before the other rules, not after those.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but maybe I haven't written very well my question.

My question is exactly to redirect all requests except the images, to index.php in order to have a url rewriting.